# How to flag a row in R if row is between two dates

Tags: r, if-statement, lubridate

I have a df1 with a column called df1$date  ( already turned into a date)

I need to create a flag called "net new" for  any rows within the df1 that land between "2022-02-01" & "2022-04-30"

Thank you so much for your help!

```r
df1 = df1 %\>% 
  mutate(Net_New = `Sales Order Line Item SO Line Create Date` %within% (
      ymd("2022-02-01"),
      ymd("2022-04-30"))
    ) == TRUE \~ TRUE
  )
```

Tried to create a column called Net New  for a TRUE and FALSE  but did not get close to it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(New_new = between(date, ymd("2022-02-01"), ymd("2022-04-30")))
```